# Displaying a video with alpha channel in HTML5

Tags: alpha

I'm trying to input a webm file with alpha channel (i.e. transparency) into a html5 website.

The video was exported succesfully to a quicktime (MOV) file with an alpha channel using Media Encoder, when I try to embed a MOV file into html it won't even play, so I did some research and learned that the best way to do this is using a webm file format, so I looked up an online converter and turned my MOV file into a webm, only now whenever I run it I still get a black square around my video, instead of the transparency I was aiming for.
Did the online converter screw up the alpha channel? Or am I missing something in my HTML (or do I need to add css or js or something?)

an example of what I want to make is this zootopia add:

http://showcase.sizmek.com/demo/zootopia-html5-interstitial (doesn't run if you have addblock)

the html I used to embed the video is this:

`<video controls>
  <source src="alphaVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>`